# Is it okay to put Object ids into the dataset attribute?

Tags: html, api, security

so I just wanted to know if putting data in a dataset of an element is considered a security flaw even though it is meant to be seen.

For example, if instagram put the id of each post from their database into the dataset attribute in each post element

Another example would be:
Putting the id of the post in a dataset

Comment: lel, your pfp is my wallpaper what a coincidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWASP calls this Insecure Direct Object Reference (IDOR) -- when you expose a "direct reference" (database ID, etc.) to an internal object to the client -- and it absolutely can be a security issue.

To quote OWASP here, which is a much better expert on this than any one person:

> IDOR do not bring a direct security issue because, by itself, it reveals only the format/pattern used for the object identifier. IDOR brings, depending on the format/pattern in place, a capacity for the attacker to mount an enumeration attack in order to try to probe access to the associated objects.

So in essence, if you surface database IDs and thus the pattern they change in, and you have some sort of access control issue (you're relying on security by obscurity, or you have some sort of bug in your access control), an attacker can find their way to *any object on your system* because they know the ID scheme all objects follow and thus can enumerate to any object in your database.

This is a major flaw, but it's by no means the only one. Check out [the OWASP cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) on this for more details!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I send my object ids from the back end to the front end? If I were to use a data attribute, I would just prerender it in using Pug/Jade, but now I have no way of getting the data unless I send another request to my API from the front end.

Comment: Do you think I should add a slug (url id) to each object item, and use that in the data-id? Or would that also be considered a security flaw. (Give the slug is a randomly generated code that has nothing to do with the object ID)

Comment: That might work! OWASP also recommends using a hash of the ID on the client-side.